# find cummulative sum in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've a repository function which would bring the total downloads by date wise

```
$downloads = Downloads::getTableName();

$model = Downloads::with([])
         ->select([
              DB::raw("date_format($downloads.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as date"),
              DB::raw("count($downloads.id) as total_count")
         ])
         ->groupBy(DB::raw("date_format($downloads.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')"))
         ->orderBy('date');

return $model->get();
```

**response**:

```
date         total_count
2022-06-01     120
2022-06-02      44
2022-06-03      12
2022-06-04      11
```

How could I get cummulative sum for this result which would look like

```
   date     total_count     cumm_total_count 
2022-06-01     120              120
2022-06-02      44              164
2022-06-03      12              176
2022-06-04      11              187
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be not to use the model.

```
$table = Downloads::getTableName();

$downloads = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::select(<<<SQL
SELECT
    date,
    total_count,
    @COUNTER := @COUNTER + total_count as cumm_total_count 
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        date(created_at) AS date,
        COUNT(1) AS total_count
    FROM
        $table
    GROUP BY
        date
) tmp_table,
(
SELECT @COUNTER := 0
) tmp_counter
SQL
);
```